# How to check if url scheme is present in a url string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to solve an issue where I need to know if there is a URL scheme (not limited to http, https) prepended to my url string. 
I could do `link.indexOf(://)`; and then take the substring of anything before the "://", but if I have a case for eg:

```
example.com?url=http://www.eg.com
```

in this case, the substring will return me the whole string i.e.
`example.com?url=http` which is incorrect. It should return me "", since my url does not have a protocol prepended.

I need to find out whether the url is prepended with a protocol or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it quite easily with a little bit of regex. The pattern `/^[a-z0-9]+:\/\//` will be able to extract it.

If you just want to test if it has it, use `pattern.test()` to get a boolean:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+:\/\//.test(url); // true
```

If you want what it is, use `url.match()` and wrap the protocol portion in parentheses:

```
url.match(/^([a-z0-9]+):\/\//)[1] // https
```

Here is a runnable example with a few example URLs.

```js
const urls = ['file://test.com', 'http://test.com', 'https://test.com', 'example.com?http'];

console.log(
  urls.map(url => (url.match(/^([a-z0-9]+):\/\//) || [])[1])
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) API which is supported in most browsers.

```
function getProtocol(str) {
    try {
        var u = new URL(str);
        return u.protocol.slice(0, -1);
    } catch (e) {
        return '';
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
getProtocol('example.com?url=http://www.eg.com'); // returns ""
getProtocol('https://example.com?url=http://www.eg.com'); // returns "https"
```

Comment: Well thats true, but what if I give you a string: 'http:/www.example.com', this should not be returning me "http" either

Comment: @user564927 Interesting. The single slash appears to act the same way in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. In fact, no slashes works too `http:www.example.com`

Comment: @user564927 Upon further investigation, it looks like a single slash is completely valid, but technically has a different meaning than a double slash. Most browsers treat single slash as user error and [correct](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32966) to double slash.