# Parse URL without protocol in Node using constructor

Tags: node.js

How can I parse successfully `www.stackoverflow.com` as a URL using the [WHATWG URL API](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#the-whatwg-url-api) in NodeJS?

If I try `new URL("www.stackoverflow.com")` I get the error error:
`URL constructor: www.stackoverflow.com is not a valid URL`.

Note: `url.parse` is [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlparseurlstring-parsequerystring-slashesdenotehost)

Comment: am I allowed to just add a protocol to the start of the given url? eg: `let parse=(url)=>url.includes('://')? new URL(url): new URL('https://'+url);`

Comment: I'm looking for something that parses URLs like [Golang does it](https://gobyexample.com/url-parsing). Go parses whatever it can from the URL. I don't want to use regexes over the URL to see what parts are there and if scheme is provided because the URL comes from user input.

Comment: behind every declarative construct there is an imperative approach though ;-; plus u don't need regex.. you can use loops and logic

Comment: checking for `://` does not work in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43742328/9698467

Comment: do all sites have `.something`? if so, the following fix works: `let parse=(url)=>!url.split('://')[0].includes('.')? new URL(url): new URL('https://'+url);`

Answer (score 3):

Simply do this:

```js
const parsedURL = new URL(url.startsWith("http") ? url : `https://${url}`);
```